Power BI Desktop (.pip) error when change to new directory - Older on local and the newest in servidor
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)
Timestamp:
2024-04-29T20:25:25.2010535Z
Local Time:
2024-04-29T17:25:25.2010535-03:00
Session ID:
2331de39-ff21-40d5-bbe9-7890e193d1e7
Release:
February 2024
Product Version:
2.126.927.0 (24.02) (x64)
Error Message:
Ocorreu um erro ao tentar abrir 'C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.pbip': Error while reading C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.SemanticModel\definition.pbidataset. DatasetDefinition: Required artifact is missing
Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Storage.FileOpenError.HandleError(IWindowService windowService, LocalizedString title)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.TryOpenOrCreateReport(IPowerBIWindowService windowService, ICurrentArtifactManager currentArtifactManager, IFileHistoryManager fileHistoryManager, CommandLine commandLine, FileType fileType, IFileInformationProtectionManager fileInformationProtectionManager, IPowerBITelemetryService telemetryService, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0()
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.IExceptionHandlerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
Stack Trace Message:
Ocorreu um erro ao tentar abrir 'C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.pbip': Error while reading C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.SemanticModel\definition.pbidataset. DatasetDefinition: Required artifact is missing
Invocation Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleKnownExceptions(Exception e)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplication(String[] args)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
InnerException0.Stack Trace Message:
Error while reading C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.SemanticModel\definition.pbidataset. DatasetDefinition: Required artifact is missing
InnerException0.Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__121.MoveNext() --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada --- em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.<MakeWithPath>d__111.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__32.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__31.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__13.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__4.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.BiProjectOperationHandler.d__31.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.BiProjectOperationHandler.d__26.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.CurrentArtifactManager.d__48.MoveNext()
InnerException0.Invocation Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception e, String prefix)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleKnownExceptions(Exception e)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplication(String[] args)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
InnerException1.Stack Trace Message:
DatasetDefinition: Required artifact is missing
InnerException1.Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectSchemaValidator.GenericParseAndValidate[T](String json, String artifactName, Boolean validateVersion)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__12`1.MoveNext()
InnerException1.Invocation Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception e, String prefix)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleKnownExceptions(Exception e)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplication(String[] args)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
OS Version:
Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0 (x64 en-US)
CLR Version:
4.8 or later [Release Number = 528049]
Peak Virtual Memory:
70 GB
Private Memory:
258 MB
Peak Working Set:
697 MB
IE Version:
11.1790.17763.0
User ID:
919a206c-3094-4b74-8b3e-139be089a1fa
Telemetry Enabled:
True
PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorCode:
InvalidReportFile
InnerException0.PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorDescription:
ProjectShredderError: Path: definition.pbidataset
InnerException1.PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorDescription:
RequiredArtifactMissing: ArtifactName: DatasetDefinition
DPI Scale:
100%
Supported Services:
Power BI
Work  - Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)
Timestamp:
2024-04-29T20:25:25.2010535Z
Local Time:
2024-04-29T17:25:25.2010535-03:00
Session ID:
2331de39-ff21-40d5-bbe9-7890e193d1e7
Release:
February 2024
Product Version:
2.126.927.0 (24.02) (x64)
Error Message:
Ocorreu um erro ao tentar abrir 'C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.pbip': Error while reading C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.SemanticModel\definition.pbidataset. DatasetDefinition: Required artifact is missing
Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Storage.FileOpenError.HandleError(IWindowService windowService, LocalizedString title)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.TryOpenOrCreateReport(IPowerBIWindowService windowService, ICurrentArtifactManager currentArtifactManager, IFileHistoryManager fileHistoryManager, CommandLine commandLine, FileType fileType, IFileInformationProtectionManager fileInformationProtectionManager, IPowerBITelemetryService telemetryService, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0()
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.IExceptionHandlerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
Stack Trace Message:
Ocorreu um erro ao tentar abrir 'C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.pbip': Error while reading C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.SemanticModel\definition.pbidataset. DatasetDefinition: Required artifact is missing
Invocation Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleKnownExceptions(Exception e)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplication(String[] args)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
InnerException0.Stack Trace Message:
Error while reading C:\Users\admlume\Komatsu Forest\KFLtda - ICT - Power BI\Projetos\BI KFBR - Telemetria\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK\BI KFBR - ALERTAS TCK.SemanticModel\definition.pbidataset. DatasetDefinition: Required artifact is missing
InnerException0.Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__121.MoveNext() --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada --- em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.<MakeWithPath>d__111.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__32.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__31.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__13.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__4.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.BiProjectOperationHandler.d__31.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.BiProjectOperationHandler.d__26.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.CurrentArtifactManager.d__48.MoveNext()
InnerException0.Invocation Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception e, String prefix)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleKnownExceptions(Exception e)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplication(String[] args)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
InnerException1.Stack Trace Message:
DatasetDefinition: Required artifact is missing
InnerException1.Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectSchemaValidator.GenericParseAndValidate[T](String json, String artifactName, Boolean validateVersion)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Packaging.Project.PBIProjectShredder.d__12`1.MoveNext()
InnerException1.Invocation Stack Trace:
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception e, String prefix)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleKnownExceptions(Exception e)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
em Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplication(String[] args)
em Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
OS Version:
Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0 (x64 en-US)
CLR Version:
4.8 or later [Release Number = 528049]
Peak Virtual Memory:
70 GB
Private Memory:
258 MB
Peak Working Set:
697 MB
IE Version:
11.1790.17763.0
User ID:
919a206c-3094-4b74-8b3e-139be089a1fa
Telemetry Enabled:
True
PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorCode:
InvalidReportFile
InnerException0.PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorDescription:
ProjectShredderError: Path: definition.pbidataset
InnerException1.PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorDescription:
RequiredArtifactMissing: ArtifactName: DatasetDefinition
DPI Scale:
100%
Supported Services:
Power BI

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
